# How do I make elementary OS Freya not lead me to the Grub on boot?

Tags: system-installation, boot

I installed elementary OS Freya yesterday - replacing Ubuntu. When I boot instead of just elementary OS the PC sends me to a grub page where I have to choose between running elementary OS or "Advanced Options for elementary OS".

How can I make the PC boot and run elementary OS Freya normally?

Answer (score 4):

Change the grub boot time out.

First, open a terminal and run this command:

```
sudo -i scratch-text-editor /etc/default/grub
```

You will see something like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` number 10 (it was line 9 for me) to any number of seconds (on my main computer I have it set to 2 seconds).

I'd advise against 0 seconds, because if you ever *need* to access grub, you will struggle - 2 is a good amount to chose.

Comment: Thank you so much for editing the question. English is not my main language, and thank you again for answering me. But unfortunately I've just go with the lame solution of re-installing Freya. Although I think it's ok to let the question here for future reference.

Comment: @AndréHeringer did reinstalling fix it?

Comment: Yep, I've uploaded my files to a MEGA account and erase the inteire disk. So now it works nicelly.